# Facing issue while running spring boot maven project in eclipse which on running gets terminated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

When I am trying to run the spring boot maven project using java application in console on top it shows  but below it shows everything is started i even included tomcat so it will be able to load in the browser too but it is not loading in the browser and gets terminated
I am not able to understand where is the issue currently so that i can run the application successfully
`Please check the POM file mentioned and the screen shot attached while running.
I had even tried removing .m2 repository and perform clean build and rerun again then too no changes appeared.`
I just wanted to launch the spring boot application in the browser so if there is any wrong in my code while running like spring-boot maven project i am right clicking on the main class and performing run as java application
I have even added dependency for using restcontroller which i am getting a classpath error where after changing the class path to .m2 repository it is still not resolved

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>springproj</groupId>
    <artifactId>springapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springapp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
        
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        
        <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
        
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

[Screen Shot of Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fneW.png)

[After adding dependency screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEzgJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are using incompatible versions in your dependencies. You should be using spring boot dependency management plugin to be on the safe side.
Replace

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

with
`spring boot starter web`

Comment: So like how to change the version since i am completely new can you show me what or how to add??

Comment: I have replaced the dependency with this spring web still getting same output in console                                                       
                                                                                                                     
      <dependency>  
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>  
<version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>  
</dependency>

Comment: Remove the version number (2. 2. 2 Release) and apply dependency management plugin